# Making a sub menu slide close at the correct time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/ktn425c6/6/

```
var $menu = $('#menu');

$menu .click(function () {
if ( $('#igna-1').css('display') != 'none' ) {
    $('#igna-1').slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $('#igna-2').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300, function() {
            $('#black, #igna, #dazed, #sons, #mad, #stimp').slideUp("fast", function() {
                $('#fatal').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
            });
        });   
    });
} else if ( $('#fatal').css('display') == 'none' ) {
    $('#fatal').animate({ left: 'toggle' }, 300, function() {
        $('#igna, #black, #dazed, #sons, #mad,  #stimp').slideToggle("fast");   
    });
}
```

1.Clicking on the WORK link opens further links.

2.Clicking on DAZED opens a sub menu.

3.With both these menus open when you click on WORK again, both menus close at the same time (which does happen on my browsers locally but for some reason not on this fiddle? You can see the full site [here](http://angelaandtom.co.uk/philipphumm.com/#))

My Question: Instead of them closing together I need the sub menu to fold away first and then the first menu. This affect does work already with the IGNA and MAD LONDON sub menus.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: either website or fiddle both fold each menu at the time here

Comment: It's when the work link is clicked again, and sub menus are open I need to the sub menu to slide in first and then the main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do you menu system like this (changed html so it is a bit more semantically correct with child links nested):

```js
$('#menu li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var li = $(this),
        subMenu = li.children('ul').eq(0);
    
    li.addClass('clicked');
    
    if (subMenu.length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if (subMenu.is(':visible')) {
            closeMenu(subMenu);
        } else {
            li.siblings().children().not(subMenu).children('li').not(':last-child').slideUp('fast', function() {
                $(this).parent().animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
            });
            
            subMenu.animate({ left: 'show' }, 300, function() {
                subMenu.children('li').not(':last-child').slideDown('fast');
                console.log('open click removed');
                li.removeClass('clicked');
            });
        }
    }
});

function closeMenu(menu) {
    var subMenu = menu.children('li').children('ul:visible').eq(0);
    if (subMenu.length) {
        closeMenu(subMenu);
    } else {
        var children = menu.children('li').not(':last-child');
        children.each(function(index) {
            if (index == children.length - 1) {
                var parentLi = menu.parent('li');
                $(this).slideUp('fast', function() {
                    menu.animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300, function() {
                        if (parentLi.length && !parentLi.hasClass('clicked')) {
                            console.log(parentLi.hasClass('clicked'));
                            closeMenu(parentLi.parent());
                        } else {
                            parentLi.removeClass('clicked');
                            console.log('close click removed');
                        }
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $(this).slideUp('fast');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```css
#menu, #menu ul, #menu li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#menu, #menu ul {
    display:inline-block;
}
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:34px;
    left:0;
}
#menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
}
#menu li {
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
}
#menu a {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    background:#ffffff;
}

#menu .level1 {
    left:100px;
}
#menu .level2 {
    left:200px;
}

#menu .level1 li {
    display:none;
}
#menu .level1 li:last-child {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li> 
        <a href="#">Work</a>
        <ul class="level1">
            <li class="hidden hover" id="dazed"> 
               <a href="#">Dazed</a>
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li class="hidden hover" id="dazed-1"><a href="#">Dazed<span class="pad">x</span>Amazon</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden hover" id="dazed-2"><a href="#">Dazed Media Re-brand</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="hidden hover" id="mad"> 
                <a href="#">MAD London</a>
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li class="hidden hover mad" id="mad-1"><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden hover mad" id="mad-2"><a href="#">Every Breaking Wave</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden hover mad" id="mad-3"><a href="#">Films Of Innocence</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden hover mad" id="mad-4"><a href="#">Holiday E-Card</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="hidden hover" id="sons"><a href="#">Sons<span class="jaap">+</span>Daughters</a></li>
            <li class="hidden hover" id="stimp"><a href="#">STIMPWHTWTIIIF</a></li>
            <li class="hidden hover" id="black"><a href="#">Graham Fan</a></li>
            <li class="hidden hover" id="igna"> 
                <a href="#">Inga Nemirovskaia</a>
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li class="hidden hover" id="igna-1"><a href="#">S/S <span id="ss">15</span></a></li>
                    <li class="hidden hover" id="igna-2"><a href="#">A/W 14</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="hidden hover" id="fatal"><a href="#">Vincenzo Laera</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but the sub menu has to slide back away before the main menu slides back.

Comment: @angela, think I have sorted it - it should close from right to left now, stopping on the element that was clicked

Comment: Thanks again pete, your code is great. The only problem I have now is adding on the other functions that affect the menu. I have tried adding my code onto the end of yours but its ruins your code. You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/7f4e0ffn/1/  How can I use your code but also keep the other functions working? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @angela, when you add your code, you are duplicating some element ids and I think this is what is spoiling the slider - for example, you have added another dazed element and some js to control the click for it - by removing the duplicate ids, it should solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7f4e0ffn/2/

Comment: Thanks, but if one clicks on any of the other links like 'joe blogs' or 'contact' and the menus are open I need them to close so only one thing is open at a time? Is this possible or too complicated? Thanks again.

Comment: It's what functions are for - if you are having repetitive code, put them in a function and call that, it makes the code a lot more manageable and maintainable in the future (as well as breaking it up into chunks where you can see what is happening a bit easier).  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7f4e0ffn/3/.